# concatenating a string and then executing the string statement using ="concatenated string"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create a string and then execute it.  By this I mean, taking 'A' and '20' concatenating them and then getting the value of A20 in that cell.

Examples:

```
="A" & "20" -> doesn't work

=(CONCATENATE("A", "20")) -> doesn't work
```

Is there an execute function in excel?
Example

```
=EXECUTE("string value")
```

so then I could create a string it would execute similar to if I typed `=string` value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do - but if you are trying to get the value in cell A20 then you want to do this:

```
=INDIRECT((CONCATENATE("A", "20")),TRUE)
```

If you are trying to just concatenate those two strings then what you are doing is fine - and it shoudl work.

If you are trying to insert the string value of "A20" into a cell then you need to copy and paste special only values on your cell with your formula - this will convert your functions into simply their actual result values.

Answer (score 1):

The 'Indirect' function is what you're looking for:  `=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A","20"))`  It returns the reference for a text string.  Here is a good MSDN article about the function: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/151323